# How does a $\Theta$ function arise in this correlator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, dirac-delta-distributions, correlation-functions

I am currently reading the paper by Coleman on Symmetry breaking in 2d, [which can be found here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103859034). On page 262 (4th page in the document), he is evaluating the following distribution:

$$
F_{\mu}(k)=\int d^2x\ e^{i k x} \langle0|j_\mu(x)\phi(0)|0\rangle.\tag{11b}$$

And finds since  $k^\mu F_\mu = 0$, that it must be $$\sigma k_\mu\delta(k^2) \Theta(k^0) + \epsilon_{\mu\nu}k^\nu \rho(k^2) \Theta(k^0).\tag{13}$$

For some number $\sigma$ and function $\rho$.

I cannot see where-ever the $\Theta(k^0)$ part is coming from, can somebody point me the right direction?

Comment: Is it correct to assume there is a fermi-surface at $k^0$? In that case the $\Theta$ functions will keep track of that surface.

Comment: @MikaelFremling I don't think so, I'm not an expert but Fermi surfaces come from periodic lattices if I recall correctly, which is not the case here (its just an arbitrary QFT in 2d).

Comment: Post about same paper: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787656/11127

Comment: @Qmechanic yes that is my post^

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally in [QFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), particles and antiparticles are defined with positive energy $k^0\geq 0$ only. (Recall that would-be negative energy states are reinterpreted as matter/antimatter of the opposite kind in order to make the vacuum stable.)

Comment: Would attempting to decompose $j_\mu$ and $\phi$ in a way similar to the Källen Lehman representation be the right way to show that the negative modes are zero?